# Visual Studio 2013 error when connecting to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm running the RC version of VS 2013 and Windows 8.1. If I go to visualstudio.com, my project and click on "Open new instance of Visual Studio", Visual Studio opens but I get a message box saying "Key not valid for use in specific state."
I've been able to work with this repository in Windows 7 just fine. So I'm assuming it has to do with the OS. Has anybody else seen this behavior?
Thanks!

Comment: I had a working install of Win8.1 and RTM VS2013 that was fine - and started getting this error when I installed Office 2013 whenever I attempt to interact with TFS.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine on my computer today in VS 2013 Premium RTM against the Service, I've tested with both TFVC and Git based team projects. I have the Git 1.8.4 installed and am running Windows 8.1 RTM.

What ever the problem is/was seems fixed if you install the latest **everything** (as I always do) :).